# Find a function by partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$, is there a general way to find an actual function $f(x,y)$?

In [this particular case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2439736/657633) the solution starts to be represented as $$f(x,y)=\int f_x dx+c(y)+A$$ In addition it is stated that if $\partial_y f_x = \partial_x f_y$ then such $f$ exists.

Given $f_x=x+y^2$ and $f_y=f_x$ we see $\partial_y f_x \not= \partial_x. f_y$. Is it saying that $f(x,y)$ cannot exist?

P.S. I did not succeed at the approach from the post by link above given my example.

Comment: There is no continuously differentiable function $f$ such that $f_x=f_y=x+y^{2}$.

Comment: $f_x=x+y^2\implies f(x,y)=x^2/2+xy^2+h(y)\implies f_y=2xy+h'(y)\ne x+y^2$ for any $h(y)$ since the terms containing $x$ are different.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question. Are you asking how to find a function, given its partials? Or are you asking how to find a particular function given a set of conditions restricting it?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I am asking how to find a function, given its partials.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How did you conclude this?

Comment: @MrBTTF You already have the answer. If $f$ is continuously differentiable then $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ (by a theorem). Since this is not satisfied in this case we conclude that no such $f$ exists.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can a discontinuously differentiable function exist here?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Partial derivatives can exist at every point without being continuous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are saying if $f_xy \not = f_yx$ then there is no continuously differentiable $f$, right? My question is if there is any function with those partial derivatives and how to find such function if there is any

Comment: @MrBTTF $x+y^{2}$ is  a continuous function, right? So if such a function exists its partial derivatives are necessarily continuous. Conclusion: there is no such function.

Comment: @MrBTTF have a look at my answer, and see if it answers your question. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have two functions of the form:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$; furthermore, suppose $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$, then  $\exists f$  s.t.    $f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $f_y=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Then, by integration we get:  $$\int \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}dx=g(x,y)+h(y)=f(x,y)$$

Note: we do not have to integrate $f_x$ we can integrate w.r.t $y$. The only difference will be that the constant of integration will be a function of the other variable.

Here, the function $h(y)$ is the constant of integration in $y$ since we are integrating w.r.t $x$.

Consequently, $$\frac {\partial}{\partial y}\int \frac{\partial f }{\partial x}dx=\frac {\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}+h'(y)=\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Given this, solve for $h'(y)$, and then integrate:

$$\int h'(y)dy$$

This will give you $$h(y)+C$$ where $C \in \mathbb R$

After that, $f(x,y)=g(x,y)+h(y)+C$.

**Why $f_{xy}$ must be equal to $f_{yx}$**

Clairaut's Theorem states if a function $f(x,y)$ is continuous and so are its second-order partial derivatives, then $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$.

Now, suppose we have continuous second order partial derivatives, but $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$. That would imply: $f(x,y)$ is not continuous. However, if you recall, if a function is differentiable, then it is continuous. In this case we have differentiability, but not continuity, which is a contradiction. Therefore, the function $f(x,y)$ does not exist. Consequently, if there is no function to begin with, then you obviously can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! Without the condition = such function $f(x, y)$ will never exist, right?

Comment: @MrBTTF Right, because otherwise the domain will have holes in it. That is, integrals on the domain will depend on the path.

Comment: what do you mean by `integrals on the domain will depend on the path`? That fundamental theorem of calculus will be wrong?

Comment: @MrBTTF ignore that, it is more of a physical explanation based on force fields and potential. I edited the answer with an explanation for why the mixed derivatives must be equal in order for us to be able to find the function. Btw, FTC will not be wrong because the conditions for FTC are not fulfilled. In fact, what we are saying is true solely because of FTC.

Comment: But what if we take the following approach?
Consider partials $f_x$ and $f_y$ where $\partial_y f_x \not= \partial_x f_y$.  Two partials give us a gradient ($f_x$;  $f_y$). Knowing the gradient we can find points of constant value of the gradient thus those points will give us level curves. So does it mean that we can find level curves for nonexistent $f$?

Comment: @MrBTTF No, no, differentiability and continuity are local phenomenon. That is why when you speak of cont. or diff. you specify your domain. When you find the level curves, you are finding the level curves for the function in the part of the plane where it is continuous, not the whole x-y plane. On the other hand, when you try to find a function given the partials you are finding a general function continuous throughout the plane. You are confusing two different things.

Comment: @MrBTTF look at this function: $\frac{xy}{x^2-2y}$ you can obviously find level curves for it, but it will not be for the whole $\mathbb R^2$ since it is discontinuous at $(2,2)$ it will be $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(2,2)\}$. Therefore, if you have partials for a function like this, then you can not find the original function.

Comment: @MrBTTF If you think I have answered your question, please do consider liking or accepting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Unfortunately you can't see my vote up because I have less than 15 reputation

Comment: I just want to go a bit further with a question if you don't mind.
You are saying differentiability and continuity are local phenomenon. That means that we can always restore not the whole function but in some parts? Given e.x  $f_x=x+y^2$ and $f_y=x+y^2$ I can find regions where $\partial_y f_x = \partial_x f_y$ and restore some parts of $f$?

Comment: @MrBTTF Yes, you definitely can but It will take a lot of guess work since you will not be able to indefinitely integrate the partials. Notice in the original answer the first step was indefinite integration, but you can indefinitely integrate a function only if it is continuous throughout the plane. Keeping that in mind, if you want to find a function given the partials you have, then you will have to, by pure guess work, find a function which differentiates to the partials in question. Regards.